# mod_python.dll into server: % 1 is not a valid win32 application

Tags: python, apache, python-module, mod-python, apache-modules

i want to Integrate python module with Apache HTTP server. I downloaded mod_Python and moved to python Lib folder. In order to integrate python with the Apache server modules i downloaded mod_python.dll and I moved it to `apache24\modules` folder. in config file of Apache I loaded

`LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.dll`

on running `httpd.exe` in command prompt it is showing syntax error as

`mod_python.dll into server: % 1 is not a valid win32 application`

How can I fix it..? please help me out....

Thanks in advance,
Srikanth.

Comment: try dependencywalker to see if there aren't missing depenency dlls. Also can be a 32/64 bit issue.

Comment: From where did you download mod_python.dll file. I am not able to find it anywhere on their site. Thanks